# Making a dynamic Form of a Quiz Quest with Title and 4 Choices in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am making a quiz site and would like to make a form for a dynamic number of questions $questions(passed to this form) and for each question there to be one text input(question title) and four text input choices(four question choices) and next to check text a radio button(to determine if this text is correct if checked the value becomes 1)

I've tried to make this functuality with for loops but havent been very successful accessing the arrays and all the tutorials on blade don't show anything similar to this

```
 <form action="{{route('quiz.storeQuestions')}}" method="POST">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    @for($i = 0; $i < $questions;$i++)
                        <input type="text" name="question[]" value="">

                        <br>

                        @for($j = 0;$j < 4;$j++)
                            Choose <input type="checkbox" name="isCorrect[{{$i}}][]" value="0" onchange="check()">
                            <input type="text" name="choice[]">
                            <br>
                        @endfor
                        <br>
                    @endfor
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit">
                </form>
```

Comment: What does your $questions array look like? I'm assuming that `name="question[]"` is where you're trying to grab the value.

Comment: $questions is just a int between 1-20 where the user picked the number of questions that quiz can have, that was submitted via dropdown box by the user in a form before being redirected to this one with $questions being passed into here

Comment: Because you're wrapping the `'question[]'` in single quotes, it's being treated as a string. Maybe use squirly brackets?

Comment: ah no thats not the issue, mainly it is how to access the isCorrect multi array of radio buttons like [ [0 => 0,1 => 0, 2=> 1, 3 => 0],[0 => 0,1 => 0, 2=> 1, 3 => 0],[0 => 0,1 => 0, 2=> 1, 3 => 0]] with 1 as the value if they were clicked and 0 if not for each set of 4 question choice text fields hence the multi dimensional